# Mutate Request Body using Mongoose Middleware

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm wondering how do I mutate or change the request body of the End-User before finally update and save the document in mongoose? like this 'save' event of mongoose middleware

```
schema.pre('save', async function () {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
```

I just want it, to do like this so

```
schema.pre('updateOne', async function () {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was just searching about the documents of mongoose and it does not fulfill my questions in my mind, so the reason I explore and I properly solve it without another execution by

```
schema.pre('updateOne', async function () {
  let data = this.getUpdate();
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, salt);
});
```

I hope, it helps :)

Comment: getUpdate() doesn't return the document? how to use .isModified() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the function inside the pre-save middleware, and use that function in your controllers, inside the route itself when updating the document and saving it, ex:

```js
// file: saltHash.js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

async function saltHash(str){
   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
   const hash = await bcrypt.hash(str, salt);
   return hash
}
module.exports = saltHash
```

```js
// file: usersRoutes.js
const saltHash = require('../utils/saltHash.js')
router.
  route('/users/:id').patch((req, res, next)=> {
   // the code, and then:
   if(req.body.password) req.body.password = saltHash(req.body.password)
   UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
  })

router
  .route('/users')
  .post((req, res, next) => {
     if(req.body.password) req.body.password = saltHash(req.body.password)
     UserModel.create(req.body)
  })
```

This is one solution.

Both routes in the example above will salt and hash the password.
This moves the logic from the **models** (middlewares) to the controllers.

For the coding style, this is not the best style... But since Mongoose is an everyday pain, it's not a problem.